# Admin not responding

Tags: admin

I have an ongoing issue with the admin. It seems to stop responding periodically. For example, I just created a new section in a site I am developing and hit save, I get spinner and it just sits there and doesn't respond. I look on the server and there is no activity. There are no javascript errors. If I reload the page the details have saved.

I am using a recent version of Chrome on Windows 8.

It seems to happen maybe every 1 out of 10 admin setting type pages

Comment: Are you on XAMPP by chance? There is a similar report using XAMPP in the comments here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11162/very-slow-page-loading-time-1-minute-regularly-on-cp-or-front-pages

Comment: no i use vagrant for dev, and i get the issue on a linode ubuntu 14 server